# After selecting mouse hover in selenium, Screen is getting disturbed. Want to know the option to change the mouse pointing

Tags: java, selenium, testing, bdd, mousehover

my code is working as it is hovering on the menu and select the element which I want to select but when it selects the element, UI is getting disturbed. Code is written in java.

```
public void HoveronMenu() {        
    Actions action = new Actions(ldriver);
    WebElement mainMenu = ldriver.findElement(Hover);
    action.moveToElement(mainMenu).moveToElement(ldriver.findElement(selectmenu)).click().build().perform(); }
```

[This is normal view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAIGl.png)

[This is the image after executing script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hhVh.png)

After selecting the element, system acquires entire space of hovering element from top to bottom and showing as a pop up. Is there any way to clear the screen after clicking on hover element?

Thanks.

Comment: Does reload page works for you ?

Comment: Yes it works for me. On large screen there is no UI issue occurring but I don't know why this is happening on my laptop.

Comment: Are you launching the browser in full screen mode  ?

Comment: Yes I am launching in full screen mode.